# Reference LEGO Technic 42043

Tags: technic

When installing the tubing starting on page 273 of the instruction booklet, the suggested length seems to be too short for the installation.  Is it permissible to cut the tubing provided to fit the situation, or am I missing something in previous construction?  If not able to cut the tubing, it becomes very congested connecting to the appropriate valve.

Instructions: http://lego.brickinstructions.com/m/lego_instructions/set/42043/Mercedes-Benz_Arocs_3245

Answer (score 5):

The provided tubes all have the correct length. If you start cutting tubes than you run into problems later on.

I have build this set multiple times an never run into problems. Make sure all tubes are routed correctly and by the shortest distance sometimes its needed to route a tube underneath another.

When you start building, what helps is sorting the different tubes by length and check if you have them all.